# How to sync datetime in centos minimal installed in virtualbox?

Tags: centos, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have installed centos 7 minimal version in VirtualBox. When I run this VM, each time I see incorrect date & time. How can I update / Sync this datetime automatically?
Current time displayed is `Wed Nov 30 10:04:24 IST 2016`.

Comment: Do you want to use the time from the host or not? By how much is the time wrong — is it a timezone issue or a clock issue?

Comment: Even if its host time, I don't have any issue. Timezone (IST) is correctly setup, as its clear from the output printed by me. `How much wrong` is unpredictable. I can simply say that guest time lags from host time, even if I correct it, on next restart, it again lags.

Comment: Do you have ntpd running inside the VM? Usually with a VM it's best to let it keep the same clock as the host, i.e. don't run NTP inside (the guest tends to be confused if it has both NTP time drift indications and the guest tools adjusting the time from the host).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using cron and ntpdate.

First set your timezone. E.g.

```
timedatectl set-timezone America/New_York
```

Create a file in cron.d having ntpdate command to sync time with ntp server.

```
vim /etc/cron.d/ntpdate
```

add below mentioned line in file

```
*/5 * * * * ntpdate 0.pool.ntp.org
```

If you have internal ntp server then point to that instead of ntp.org.

This will sync system time with ntp server after every 5 min.

Comment: I couldn't find `/etc/cron.d/ntpdate`, but I added this entry using `crontab -e`. I've set timezone while installation, so skipped this too. Thanks :)